# How to invoke Lambda asynchronously via Application Load Balancer? (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer

Using AWS, wondering if anyone has managed to invoke a lambda asynchronously via an ALB before?

I've seen API Gateway examples and CLI examples and thought it should be a similar process however nothing has worked so far. The examples mention passing the invocation type to the header which I have tried ("X-Amzn-Invocation-Type" and "Invocation-Type" with "Event").

From Cloudwatch logs I can see the header being passed but it is not the expected behaviour.

An example, Lambda returns some html with 'Hello World'.

`curl -i -X POST -H "X-Amz-Invocation-Type:Event" http://{alb.name}/{path}`

Expected response is either 200 or 202

Actual response is

```
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Tue, 25 May 2021 13:06:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 246
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <style>
    html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    font-family: arial; font-weight: 700; font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello World from Lambda</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Cloudwatch logs headers are as follows

```
{
    "body": "",
    "requestContext": {
        "elb": {
            "targetGroupArn": "{arn}"
        }
    },
    "queryStringParameters": {},
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "x-amz-invocation-type": "Event",
        "x-forwarded-port": "80",
        "x-forwarded-for": "10.0.233.231",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "user-agent": "curl/7.61.1",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-60acf23c-6f1772565f7fbf070f0dd1a9",
        "host": "{alb}",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "http"
    },
    "path": "{path}",
    "isBase64Encoded": "False"
}
```

Just wondering if anyone has managed to successfully call a lambda asynchronously via an ALB or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Different services invoke AWS Lambda differently :

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/understanding-the-different-ways-to-invoke-lambda-functions/

ELB invokes it synchronously. That said, the documentation is rather inaccurate. API Gateway by default does a synchronous invocation, but with a custom integration and appropriate headers, API Gateway can invoke lambda asynchronously. The ability to invoke asynchronously is built into API Gateway. From the looks of it, this is not present in ELBs like ALB, atleast not in a documented fashion.

There are round about ways but if you are considering those, I guess an API Gateway based solution might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the ALB invoke the Lambda function asynchronously, but you can have it invoke a Lambda that invokes the target asynchronously and returns with a 202 response.
An alternative to the asynch invocation would be to do it through an SQS queue, which gives better monitoring and retry mechanisms.